# Update from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 changed fonts

Tags: 13.10, 14.04, fonts

I just upgraded my Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04, but now all the fonts look different and I really would like to have the old fonts back. I tried to use other fonts but they also look rather bad.

So how can I get the old fonts back?
To me it seems like the font definitions it self have changed ...